# Turning For Loop into Multiprocessing loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have been working on this code for a while now and have got everything working but I would just like it to update quicker when the button is pressed. I was looking into multiprocessing but I am new to python so I'm a little confused on how to turn this for loop in the def click() into a multiprocessing version so they can run simultaneously. I have cut some of the code and GUI setup out to make the code more bearable but that is why some variables may seem unnecessary. Any advice would be great. Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
options.headless = True
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Matt/Downloads/chromedriver', options=options)

app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Over / Under")

#Entries for user to insert player name that will be searched

p1 = tk.StringVar()
p2 = tk.StringVar()
p3 = tk.StringVar()

Player1Name = tk.Entry(app, textvariable = p1, width=20)
Player1Name.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.N)
Player2Name = tk.Entry(app, textvariable = p2, width=20)
Player2Name.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.S)
Player3Name = tk.Entry(app, textvariable = p3, width=20)
Player3Name.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=tk.S)

#Empty label that will be filled with current stats

P1CurrentStatText = tk.StringVar()
P2CurrentStatText = tk.StringVar()
P3CurrentStatText = tk.StringVar()

P1CurrentStatLabel = tk.Entry(app, width=5, textvariable = P1CurrentStatText)
P1CurrentStatLabel.grid(column=5, row=0, padx=10, pady=5)
P2CurrentStatLabel = tk.Entry(app, width=5, textvariable = P2CurrentStatText)
P2CurrentStatLabel.grid(column=5, row=1, padx=10, pady=5)
P3CurrentStatLabel = tk.Entry(app, width=5, textvariable = P3CurrentStatText)
P3CurrentStatLabel.grid(column=5, row=2, padx=10, pady=5)

def click():
    for i in range(1, 6):
        pID = eval(("p" + str(i) + ".get()"))
        pcID = eval(("P" + str(i) + "CurrentStatText"))
        PRAID = eval(("PRA" + str(i) + "opt.get()"))
        OUID = eval(("OU" + str(i) + "opt.get"))
        if pID == "":
            continue
        browser.get("https://www.espn.com/")
        time.sleep(1)
        srch_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-search-trigger"]')
        srch_btn.click()
        srch_bar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-search"]/input[1]')
        srch_bar.send_keys(pID)
        time.sleep(1)
        player_page = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="global-search"]/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/a')
        player_page.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        points = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="fittPageContainer"]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/article[1]/ul/li/div/div')
        rebounds = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="fittPageContainer"]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/article[2]/ul/li/div/div')
        assists = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="fittPageContainer"]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/article[3]/ul/li/div/div')
        pointstxt = points.get_property('textContent')
        reboundstxt = rebounds.get_property('textContent')
        assiststxt = assists.get_property('textContent')

        if PRAID == "Rebounds":
            pcID.set(reboundstxt)
        elif PRAID == "Points":
            pcID.set(pointstxt)
        else:
            pcID.set(assiststxt)

def quit():
    app.destroy()
    browser.close()

UpdateButton = tk.Button(app, text = 'Update', command = click)
UpdateButton.grid(column=2, row=5, pady=10, padx = 10)

ExitButton = tk.Button(app, text = 'Exit', command = quit)
ExitButton.grid(column=4, row=5, pady=10, padx = 10)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: first you should put code from loop in function because theading/multiprocessing will need function's name as argument.

Comment: BTW:  theading/multiprocessing will need `queue` to send result back to main process - other processes don't have access to GUI - and main process will update GUI. But it may need `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to check periodically if there is new message in queue.

Comment: Is there anyway that you could show an example of this and maybe use some of my code to display it? I'm pretty new to this so any visualization with my code or variable would help me a lot.

Comment: BTW: you could keep elements on list and then you can use `p[i].get()` instead of using `eval()`

Comment: every  thead/process will have to start own selenium when you click button and it may need some time - so it may run slower then all in one thread.

Comment: so would you recommend something different to complete this faster?

Comment: it would be good to do it without selenium. For example I can get "search" data (for query `markel`) in JSON format using `requests` with url https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/search?region=us&lang=en&query=markel&limit=5&mode=prefix&type=player   Maybe this way it could get details

Answer (score 0):

`Selenium` is slow. Using `multiprocessing` it would have to start new `Selenium` and `browser` in every process at every start of process.

Digging in `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` I found urls used by page to get data as JSON.

Search:

```
url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/search?region=us&lang=en&query={}&limit=5&mode=prefix&type=player'.format(query)
```

Details:

```
url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/athletes/{}/overview?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn'.format(id_)
```

Using `requests` I can get data for one player in 1.9 seconds - so it doesn't even need multiprocesses. It would need only use it with `tkinter`.

I don't know only if there is no need to add some cookies or header.

```
import requests
import time

def get_data(query):

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/search?region=us&lang=en&query={}&limit=5&mode=prefix&type=player'.format(query)

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    id_ = data['items'][0]['id']
    name = data['items'][0]['displayName'] 

    #url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/athletes/{}?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn'.format(id_)
    #r = requests.get(url)
    #data = r.json()

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/athletes/{}/overview?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn'.format(id_)
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    labels = data['nextGame']['statistics']['labels']
    stats = data['nextGame']['statistics']['splits'][0]['stats']

    return (id_, name, labels, stats)

# --- main ---

start = time.time()

query = 'markell'

id_, name, labels, stats = get_data(query)

print('id:', id_)
print('name:', name)
for l, s in zip(labels, stats):
    print(l, s)

end = time.time()
print('time:', end-start, 's')
```

Result:

```
id: 4065699
name: Markell Johnson
GP 1
MIN 38.0
FG% 28.6
3P% 0.0
FT% 62.5
REB 4.0
AST 6.0
BLK 0.0
STL 1.0
PF 3.0
TO 3.0
PTS 9.0
time: 1.8497259616851807 s
```

In JSON data there are other information.

---

**EDIT:** tkinter GUI which use it. It works fast but it would use also `threading` to work faster.

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests
import time

# --- functions ---

def get_data(query):

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/search?region=us&lang=en&query={}&limit=5&mode=prefix&type=player'.format(query)

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    id_ = data['items'][0]['id']
    name = data['items'][0]['displayName'] 

    #url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/athletes/{}?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn'.format(id_)
    #r = requests.get(url)
    #data = r.json()

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/basketball/mens-college-basketball/athletes/{}/overview?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn'.format(id_)
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    labels = data['nextGame']['statistics']['labels']
    stats = data['nextGame']['statistics']['splits'][0]['stats']

    return (id_, name, labels, stats)

def click():

    for i in range(NUMBER):
        query = entry_players[i].get().strip()
        print(i, 'query:', query)
        if query:
            id_, player, names, stats = get_data(query)

            print('id:', id_)
            print('player:', player)

            parts = []
            for l, s in zip(names, stats):
                text = '{}: {}'.format(l,s)
                print(text)
                parts.append(text)

            print(entry_stats[i])
            entry_stats[i].delete('0', 'end')    
            entry_stats[i].insert('end', '; '.join(parts))
            root.update() # force tkinter to redraw widget

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1) # to resize column `Stats`

entry_players = []
entry_stats = []

tk.Label(root, text='Player').grid(column=0, row=0)
tk.Label(root, text='Stats').grid(column=1, row=0)

NUMBER = 3
for i in range(NUMBER):
    e = tk.Entry(root)
    e.grid(column=0, row=i+1)
    entry_players.append(e)

    e = tk.Entry(root)
    e.grid(column=1, row=i+1, sticky='we') # `sticky` to resize column `Stats`
    entry_stats.append(e)

print(entry_stats)

b = tk.Button(root, text='Search', command=click)
b.grid(column=0, row=NUMBER+1)

b = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
b.grid(column=1, row=NUMBER+1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much. What should I look up in order to learn more about how to use this tool, so I don't have to keep asking you for help? Also, I may have misread something but could this work with tkinter?

Comment: I added example which uses `tkinter` to display it. It still could use `threading` to run `requests` at the same time but it would need other changes (`root.after()`).

Comment: as for `DevTools` I don't know one place for information - I always use Google to find some information about `DevTool`, `HTTP`, `HTML`, `JavaScript`, `JSON`, `XPath` etc.

Comment: How would I make it only print something like rebounds or one single stat instead of all of the stats that were printed?

Comment: using `data = dict(zip(names, stats))` you get dictionary like `{"GP": 13, "PTS": '9,1', ...}`  and then you can get `data["PTS"]` or `data["REB"]`

Comment: where exactly would I make those changes within the code that you had posted?